# How to apply RewriteRule properly on forbidden files?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2.4, errordocument

### The goal

If the request is `http://⋯/.htaccess`,
do **not** display the content of that file,
show an ErrorDocument 403 instead,
rewriting **only** `http://` to `https://`.

### The problem

The URL is rewritten to `https://⋯/403.shtml`,
instead of the desired `https://⋯/.htaccess`.

### The details

The ErrorDocument 403 and the protection of the
.htaccess are set up by the web hosting provider.

The HTTPS rewrite is set up in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$0 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: The URL is not rewritten at all, if `ErrorDocument 403 "Forbidden"` is appended to the .htaccess file. It remains `http://⋯/.htaccess` instead of the desired `https://⋯/.htaccess`.

Comment: `http://⋯/non-existent` is properly rewritten to `https://⋯/non-existent`, regardless the type of `ErrorDocument 404` (whether it's a customized message or an internal redirect). So I guess the culprit is not the ErrorDocument directive, but the supposed `Require all denied` directive in the main configuration file, protecting the .htaccess files.

Comment: `http://⋯/.htaccess` should just return `403` There won't be any redirect to https for a 403 status URL

Comment: @anubhava I want all the pages of this website to be served using HTTPS, including the error pages. I don't want the users to think that the site is (partially) unsafe.

Comment: What is `ErrorDocument 403` set to in server config?

Comment: @anubhava I do not have access to the main configuration file (`httpd.conf`), but I guess it contains `ErrorDocument 403 /403.shtml`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<If "%{HTTPS} != 'on'">
    Require all granted
    RewriteEngine on    
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA,R=301]
</If>
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: Nice solution (+1). The `<If>` expression changes the order of processing so that it can override the 403 response generated in the server config. However, you do still need to ensure the `ErrorDocument` is not _redirecting_ to the `403.shtml` document, as mentioned in my answer, otherwise you'll get a 301, followed by a 302 (and potentially no 403 at all).

Comment: However, I would still question whether you should be doing this for potentially "malicious" requests to system files (like `.htaccess` itself as mentioned in the question). In this case, a minimal 403 response (no redirect) would be preferable - regardless of whether the request is HTTP or HTTPS, instead of a 301 (over HTTP), followed by a 403 (over HTTPS). Any 403s that your _application_ generates should be after the redirect to HTTPS anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Set the following in your `.htaccess` file to reset the default 403 Apache `ErrorDocument`:

```
ErrorDocument 403 default
```

> The ErrorDocument 403 and the protection of the .htaccess are set up by the web hosting provider.

It looks like the host has configured the `ErrorDocument` directive with an absolute URL to the `403.shtml` document, which will naturally trigger a 302 redirect instead of an internal subrequest.

Comment: I've set it to default. Now I get the simple hardcoded error message "*Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.*". Unfortunatelly, the URL is still `http://⋯/.htaccess` instead of `https://⋯/.htaccess`. I think the external redirect is modified by a supposed `Require all denied` directive in the main configuration file, protecting the .htaccess files.

Comment: "Unfortunatelly, the URL is still http" - Yes, is that really a problem? But it's a 403, not a 302 (as before I assume). Issuing a 3xx redirect provides no better security. If you need more security then consider implementing HSTS (so the _browser_ requests HTTPS from the beginning - no redirect). The request is blocked in the server config, before `.htaccess` is able to run.

Comment: It is **not** better to redirect to HTTPS _before_ issuing the 403. You should respond with a 403 on the HTTP request (which is what this now does). The "problem" you had here was the external redirect to `403.shtml`.

Comment: Is it still safe without HTTPS, if the 403 error page is dynamically generated, containing the name and profile photo of the user, and some personalized navigation links, based on the site-browsing history of the user?

Comment: This is _only_ for requests to `.htaccess` that are bocked by the server config - which a normal user should never be requesting in the first place?! Other "personalised" 403s that _you_ trigger can be behind HTTPS. You don't need to serve the same 403 response for _all_ requests. (But why does a 403 contain the name and profile photo of the user?!) Yes, any "personal" information sent over an HTTP response can potentially be snooped. (Obviously a 3xx redirect response that redirects to HTTPS is also sent over an insecure HTTP response, this could also contain "information", but probably not.)

Comment: `.htaccess` is not the only file that's blocked in this directory. All the blocked files result in `https://⋯/403.shtml` instead of `https://⋯/a-random-blocked-file`.

Comment: Other system files blocked by the server config or files that _you_ are blocking? But with `ErrorDocument 403 default` you then get a simple direct response - which is good. And you can then override this with a custom 403 (which you appear to be doing) in which you can check the URL-path and return a customised response based on the URL that has been requested. If you want, your custom 403 could also trigger a 302 redirect to HTTPS (for select URLs that contain more personal information). However, if security really is a concern then consider implementing HSTS.

Comment: (Although I would exercise caution with implementing HSTS - or at least the "preload" list - on a shared server. See also: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250805/hsts-recommendations-in-htaccess)

Comment: My question is how to do this. Your answer is not to do this. So my new question is why not to do this? In the meantime, [I've figured out the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66367335/1293492), so I'm even more curious now: what's wrong with doing this?

Comment: I wasn't saying "not to do this", I was suggesting you could do this _in_ your custom 403 error document (serve a custom response based on the URL _or_ redirect) now that the _redirect_ to `403.shtml` has been removed. To be honest, I was struggling with how to do this in `.htaccess` alone (having to _override_ the server generated 403 response). However, I would still question whether you _needed_ to do this for requests to system files. Personally, I would block requests to `.htaccess` (and similar system files) with a minimal response, since this is most likely a malicious request.